# ImportError . No module named Commons error - python

Tags: python, linux, bash, importerror

Hi I have a project which it's made up of a couple of folders named Proj1 and Proj2.

```
Home
    Proj1
       Scripts1.py

    Proj2
       Scripts2.py

    Commons.py
```

In Scripts1 I set

```
sys.path.append('/Home')
os.chdir('/Home')
```

and `import Commons` which contains function useful for every scripts.
The whole project is on a Linux server.  I run the scripts with a bash

```
script_name=Scripts1
script_file="/Home/Proj1/${script_name}.py"
python "$script_file"
```

I keep getting error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Commons'`. What Am I missing?

Comment: What output do you receive when you print(sys.path)?

Comment: list paths, including the path /Home I've just set.

Comment: `import Commons` but not `import Commons.py`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pick a top-level name for your module, then arrange your code like this:

```
Home
  script_name.py
  somename
    Common.py
    Proj1
      Scripts1.py
    Proj2
      Scripts2.py
```

Then use `import somename` and use `somename.Common` within the module itself and `somename.Proj1.Scripts1` etc. Also, you probably want to move `script_name.py` outside of the module directory itself as shown.